# Create setup for application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I want to create setup for my application and I want to know the differences and advantages of creating setup with `Visual Studio Installer` and `InstallShield LE`. Which of these is better?

I use visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Choosing a Windows Installer Deployment Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500.aspx) for a comparison of features.

The page also cautions that Visual Studio Installer project templates will not be included in future versions.